# Converting Bing 6.1 to 7.0

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I got this code which works 100% correctly using the Bing Maps Api V6.1
But i wan't to use it using the newest api version(7.0) I do really need help to convert it. So if anyone have any tips of where im going to start or maybe you got an link with an tutorial. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head> <title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
ul, li {margin:0;padding:0;}

ul.pmenu
{
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1px;
    list-style: none;
    width: 150px; /* Width of Menu Items */
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background: #235087;
    z-index:10;
}

ul.pmenu li { position: relative; }

ul.pmenu li a
{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: White;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 20px;
}

ul.pmenu li a:hover
{
    background:#335EA8;
    color:white;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var map = null;
function GetMap() {
    map = new VEMap('myMap');
    map.LoadMap();
    map.AttachEvent("onclick", ShowPopupMenu);
}
function ShowPopupMenu(e) {
if (!e.rightMouseButton) {
    RemovePopupMenu();
    return;
}

var menu = document.getElementById('popupmenu');

menu.style.display = 'block'; //Showing the menu
menu.style.left = e.clientX + "px"; //Positioning the menu
menu.style.top = e.clientY + "px";
}

function RemovePopupMenu() {
document.getElementById("popupmenu").style.display = 'none';
} 
</script>
</head>
<body onload="GetMap();">
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="popupmenu" class="pmenu">
        <li><a href="#" onclick='RemovePopupMenu(); alert("First");'>First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick='RemovePopupMenu(); alert("Second");'>Second</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick='RemovePopupMenu();'>Exit</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 <div id='myMap' style="position:relative; width:1000px; height:800px;"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try look at : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx

I made up a little fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nPPqV/1/

But now I've got a credential error, because I don't have a dev account on MS.

```
EDIT:
```

new working version http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nPPqV/4/

```
EDIT:
```

final fully working version: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/nPPqV/5/

Answer (score 0):

I guess it would be something like this:

```
var map = null;
function GetMap() {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), {credentials:"Bing Maps Key"});
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'click', ShowPopupMenu);
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(map, 'rightclick', RemovePopupMenu);
}
```

**Edit:**

Your ShowPopupMenu would probably have to use the pageX and pageY properties instead, like this.

```
function ShowPopupMenu(e) {

var menu = document.getElementById('popupmenu');

menu.style.display = 'block'; //Showing the menu
menu.style.left = e.pageX + "px"; //Positioning the menu
menu.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
}
```

**Documentation references:**

- Map: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427609.aspx
- Events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406731.aspx

Comment: How do you mean didn't work, JavaScript errors, wrong behavior, or what? Have you changed your reference to use 7.0 of the API, instead of 6.1?

Comment: @Parek For version 7.0 you need an API-key, have you got one, and have you replace med "Bing Maps Key" with your key, as the credentials-option?

Comment: @Parek See my updated answer. If that doesn't help, you really need to provide some more info. Do you get any JavaScript errors, and in that case, what do they say?

Comment: I still don't get any JavaScript errors. The only thing is that the menu doesn't show up. I tested for some reason to take away the "check if its right click" part. And then the menu showed up. But not on the clicked position. It's position was kinda wierd.

Comment: @Parek if you skip preventing the right click, then I think my update version of ShowPopupMenu would work.

Comment: I tested it, the menu's position is more "positive" than before but it's isn't exact. I think that calling e.pageX and e.pageY is wrong because you want to know the position of the map not the page.

Comment: How to do you want it positioned? Should be upper-left corner of the menu appear where the mouse was clicked?

Comment: Sorry my fault. The position is fine. The problem now is that the map doesn't work with the right click function.

Comment: @Parek Try my updated GetMap function, that adds a handler for right click as well.